# How to add element to that variable list like this "List<Object[]> listObject" in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, variables, element

I don't know how to add element if the type data in squareBracket is array.

Comment: `listObject.add(new Object[]{});`

Comment: Where you want to add element

Comment: In list or in object array of list

Comment: i want to add element in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add element in List then simply do:

```
listObject.add(new Object[]{});
```

Or if you want to add to Object array inside list then use (Which is quite a long root due to restrictive behavior of array data structure, **Thats why ArrayList is alternative to achieve this.** ):

```
    @Test
    public void testArray()  {


        List<Object[]> listObjects =  new ArrayList<>();
        listObjects.add(new Object[]{1,2});
         addX( listObjects.get(0).length , listObjects.get(0) , 3);

        listObjects.set(0,addX( listObjects.get(0).length , listObjects.get(0) , 3));

        System.out.println(listObjects.get(0));
    }

    public Object[] addX(int n, Object arr[], Object x)
    {
        int i;

        // create a new array of size n+1
        Object newarr[] = new Object[n + 1];

        // insert the elements from
        // the old array into the new array
        // insert all elements till n
        // then insert x at n+1
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            newarr[i] = arr[i];

        newarr[n] = x;

        return newarr;


    }
```